# Conflict in including of a file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to include a file which generates 2 random numbers that needs to be add or what we call captcha. I have two logins: one that requires employee id, birthdate, and the captcha answer(Which I call the easy login). While the other one requires your first name, last name, birthdate, and captcha(I call it the standard login). So I have two radio buttons for the user to choose whether an easy login or standard login. So I'm encountering this problem when you choose a login then you need to answer the captcha (The captcha sends sessions for its answer) so whats happening right know is that the captcha in the easy login is always being override by the captcha in the standard login. What I thought that I would do is set a condition where if the radio button is selected (easy login) then thats the time it will be included. But I don't know how to do that.

Here is the captcha code:
**captcha.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$n1=rand(1,6); //Generate First number between 1 and 6  
$n2=rand(5,9); //Generate Second number between 5 and 9  
$answer=$n1+$n2;  

$math = "What is ".$n1." + ".$n2." ? ";  
$_SESSION['vercode'] = $answer;

print $math;

?>
```

Then here is the code for my interface:

**index.php**

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">

function toggleTables(which)
{

if(which == "0") {

    document.getElementById('standard').style.display = "table";
    document.getElementById('customize').style.display = "none";
    }
    if(which == "1") {

    document.getElementById('customize').style.display = "table";
    document.getElementById('standard').style.display = "none";
    }
}

</SCRIPT>

</head>
<body style="background: url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;" >
<a href="http://i-refer.elitebpocareers.com" align="center"><?php include('../include/logoheader.php'); ?></a>




<div class="row">
<div class="twelve columns">
    <hr />
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="two columns">

</div>

<div class="eight columns">
    <div class="content">

        <?php include('../include/retain-empid.php'); ?>

        <br>

        <input name="radio" type="radio" id="customize_1" onClick="toggleTables('0')" value="radio" /><font color="white">Standard Login</font>
        <input name="radio" type="radio" id="customize_0" onClick="toggleTables('1')" value="radio" checked="checked"/><font color="white">Easy Login</font>

        <form name="loginform" action="login_exec.php" method="post" >

        <center><?php include('../function/login_errmsg.php'); ?></center>


        <table width="100%" class="imagetable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="customize">
                <tr>
                <th colspan="4">
                    Easy Log-in For Registered Convergys Employees
                </th>
            </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        <label>Employee Number</label>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Employee Number" name="txt_EmpID" autoComplete="off" value=<?php echo $value; ?> >
                    </td>

                <td align="right">
                        <label>Birthday</label>
                    </td>


                <td>
                    <input type="date" class="" placeholder="Birthday" id="txt_BDate" name="txt_BDate" autoComplete="off" maxlength = "10" 
                    style ="width:170px;"/>
                </td>

                </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <label class="labels" align="center">
                        <strong>
                        </strong>   
                    </label>
                    </td>
                <td>
                <?php
                include ('../include/mathcaptcha.php');
                ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="captcha" type="text" placeholder="Answer to math question">
                </td>

                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="btn_refer" class="btn" value="Submit" 
                    style=" width: 170px; height: 30px; font-size: 11pt; ">
                    </td>
                </tr>

        </table>
        </form>

        <form action="otherlogin_exec.php" method="post"> 
        <table width="100%" class="imagetable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="standard" style="display: none">

                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4">
                        Standard Log-in For All Registered Users
                    </th>
                </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align = "right">
                    <label>First name:</label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="txtFirstName" autoComplete="off" >
                </td>

                <td>
                    <label>Last name:</label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="txtLastName" autoComplete="off" >
                </td>
                </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Birthday:</label>
                </td>

                    <td>
                    <input type="date" class="" placeholder="Birthday" id="txt_BDate" 
                    name="txtPassword" autoComplete="off" maxlength = "10" style = "width:170px;"/>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <label class="labels" align="center">
                        <strong>

                        </strong>   
                    </label>

                </td>
                <td>
                <?php
                include ('../include/mathcaptcha.php');
                ?>
                </td>                   
                <td>
                    <input name="captcha" type="text" placeholder="Answer to math question">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>

                <td>
                </td>

                <td>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="btn_refer" class="btn" value="Submit" 
                    style=" width: 100%; height: 30px; font-size: 11pt; ">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're generating two different sets of random numbers. Why not include the captcha file once then echo the values it generates where needed? You can include at the top of the file and add a comment to make it clearer. Also don't echo(print; output) in the file you're including just set the values.

Comment: I've tried including it once but it would ruin the design so I'm thinking of a way to set a condition where it would be included once the specific radio button for that login is ticked.

Comment: you can use ajax to send request to captcha.php in the script of index.php and in response from captcha.php you can get captcha code. no need to include directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the first line of your file

`<?php include_once ('../include/mathcaptcha.php'); ?`>

then change the lines from

```
      <td>
            <?php
            include ('../include/mathcaptcha.php');
            ?>
            </td>
```

to

```
      <td><?php echo $math;?></td>
```

and take the print out of the captcha file. PHP doesnt affect the design of pages only the outputted data does which should be altered as needed.